# Acknowledgement that databases updated in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In my code I want to know after db.SaveChanges(), that whether the database has been updated or not. Is there any mechanism that when the SaveChanges() methods is successful I can get a value returned on the basis of which I can take some decision.

Comment: Use the dynamic ViewBag. The following post is helpful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108941/asp-net-mvc-showing-specific-html-after-post

Answer (score 3):

[SaveChanges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) returns an integer representing the number of objects that have been saved to the database.

If there is a failure , an exception is always thrown on SaveChanges()

In addition if you want to check whether your newly added or updated entity is saved.You can check what is the number returned by SaveChanges().